# Does Visual Studio offer a way to catch an add/remove/edit Reference event that isn't specified for only C# or VB projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, visual-studio-2012, envdte

I found this documentation in the MSDN Library:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228956.aspx

It specifies a way to catch Add, Edit, or Delete Reference events within Visual Studios. However, this only works for C# and VB projects. I have implemented a Visual Studio extension with a custom project type so these events are not fired within my custom Projects.

My question is if Visual Studio offers a way to catch a generalized version of the Add, Edit, or Remove Reference events?